# How to define schema when I want to use annotations with overblog graphql?

Tags: symfony, annotations, graphql

I want to use annotations with overblog graphql in symfony. When i create a provider with an query I get an error about the schema.

error: At least one schema should be declare

I don`t know how to config the schema in the config file. Normally I use yaml as type.

When I use the defaults it`s using CoreQuery what`s pointing to the yaml config file. I don`t know how to change this for using annotations in php. When I remove the schema from definitions i get the same error.

What do I need to change to use annotation with overblog graphql bundle?

/config/packages/graphql.yaml

```
overblog_graphql:
  definitions:
    schema:
      default:
        query: CoreQuery
#        mutation: CoreMutation

    show_debug_info: '%kernel.debug%'
    mappings:
      auto_discover: false
      types:
        - type: annotation
          dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/GraphQL"
          suffix: ~
```

/src/Graphql/Types/SensorProviders.php

```php
namespace App\Graphql\Types;

use Overblog\GraphQLBundle\Annotation as GQL;

/**
 * @GQL\Provider
 */
class SensorProviders {

    /**
     * @GQL\Query(type="[Sensor]", name="sensors")
     */
    public function getSensors() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

/src/Graphql/Types/Sensor.php

```php
namespace App\Graphql\Types;

use Overblog\GraphQLBundle\Annotation as GQL;

/**
 * @GQL\Type
 */
class Sensor
{
    /**
     * @GQL\Field(type="Integer!")
     */
    public $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, but after hours of debugging, i figured it out:

With your `graphql.yaml` you would need following additional file:
`/src/Graphql/Types/CoreQuery.php`:

```php
namespace App\Graphql\Types;

use Overblog\GraphQLBundle\Annotation as GQL;

/**
 * @GQL\Type
 */
class CoreQuery
{
}
```

Basically you need to define an empty root type and all annotated queries get automatically added.
Same for mutations.